# Data rearrangement in R

Tags: python, r, dataframe, data.table

I have several CSV files like so:

```
site,run,id,payload,dir
1,1,1,528,1
1,1,1,540,2
1,1,3,532,1
# ... thousands more rows ...
```

(In the actual case I'm working with, there are three files with a grand total of 1,408,378 rows.)  For plotting, I want to reshuffle them into this format:

```
label,stream,dir,i,payload
A,1,1,1,586
A,1,1,2,586
A,1,1,3,586
# etc
```

where 'label' is derived from the name of the CSV file; 'stream' is a serial number assigned to each combination of 'site', 'run', and 'id' within one file (so, unique only within 'label'); 'i' is the row number within each 'stream'; and 'dir' and 'payload' are taken directly from the original file.  I also want to discard all but the first 20 rows of each stream.  I know in advance that every cell in the CSV file (except the header) is a positive integer, and that 'dir' only ever takes the values 1 and 2.

I killed my initial attempt to do this, with `plyr`, because after more than an hour of computation it had run the R process up to 6GB of working set with no end in sight.  The shiny new support for `foreach` parallelism in the latest `plyr` did not help: eight processes ran for 10 minutes of CPU time each and then it went back down to one process, which continued for another hour and, yep, blew out my RAM again.

So then I wrote myself a helper script in Python, with which I am far more fluent:

```
import sys
def processOne(fname):
    clusters = {}
    nextCluster = 1
    with open(fname + ".csv", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == "site,run,id,payload,dir": continue
            (site, run, id, payload, dir) = line.split(',')
            clind = ",".join((site,run,id))

            clust = clusters.setdefault(clind,
                                        { "i":nextCluster, "1":0, "2":0 })
            if clust["i"] == nextCluster:
                nextCluster += 1

            clust[dir] += 1
            if clust[dir] > 20: continue

            sys.stdout.write("{label},{i},{dir},{j},{payload}\n"
                             .format(label=fname,
                                     i=clust["i"],
                                     dir=dir,
                                     j=clust[dir],
                                     payload=payload))

sys.stdout.write("label,stream,dir,i,payload\n")
for fn in sys.argv[1:]: processOne(fn)
```

and invoked it from the R script:

```
all <- read.csv(pipe("python preprocess.py A B C", open="r"))
```

Done in five seconds.

So the question is: what's the *proper* way to do this in R?  Not this specific task, but this class of problems.  I nearly always need to shuffle the data around a bunch before analyzing it and it nearly always winds up being easier in some other language -- both for me to write the code and for the computer to execute it.   Which leaves me feeling that I am only using R as an interface to `ggplot2` and maybe I would save myself time in the long run if I learned `matplotlib` instead.

Answer (score 8):

R code to accomplish the desired steps:

--"where 'label' is derived from the name of the CSV file; "

```
filvec <- list.files(<path>)
for (fil in filvec) {  #all the statements will be in the loop body
  dat <- read.csv(fil)
  dat$label <- fil   # recycling will make all the elements the same character value
```

--" 'stream' is a serial number assigned to each combination of 'site', 'run', and 'id' within one file (so, unique only within 'label'); "

```
 dat$stream <- as.numeric( with(dat, interaction(site, run, id) ) )
```

--" 'i' is the row number within each 'stream'; "

```
dat$i <- ave(dat$site,     # could be any column since we are not using its values
             dat$stream,   # 'ave' passes grouped vectors, returns same length vector
             FUN= function(x) 1:length(x) )
```

--" and 'dir' and 'payload' are taken directly from the original file."

```
 # you can refer to them by name or column number
```

--"I also want to discard all but the first 20 rows of each stream. "

```
 out <- dat[dat$i <= 20,     # logical test for the "first 20"
             c('label','stream','dir','i','payload') ]  # chooses columns desired
     }  # end of loop
```

Actually at the moment this will overwrite the three 'dat' files. (So would mainly be useful for a onetime test run for speed check.)  You could make that last call something like:

```
  assign(paste(fil, "out", sep="_"), dat[dat$i <= 20,
                                          c('label','stream','dir','i','payload') ] )
```

Comment: I believe that in your call to `ave()`, the line `function(x) 1:length(x)` needs instead to be `FUN=function(x) 1:length(x)` (the formal argument having to be explicitly given because it comes after `...` in the list of formals).

Comment: Right. I keep forgetting that.

Answer (score 6):

The `data.table` package often speeds up operations on large-to-huge data.frames.

As an example, the code below takes three 500,000-row data.frames as input, and carries out all the transformations you described in ~2 seconds on my none-too powerful laptop.

```
library(data.table)

## Create a list of three 500000 row data.frames
df <- expand.grid(site=1:2, run=1:2, id=1:2)
df <- data.frame(df, payload=1:1000, dir=rep(1, 5e5))
dfList <- list(df, df, df)
dfNames <- c("firstCSV", "secondCSV", "thirdCSV")

## Manipulate the data with data.table, and time the calculations
system.time({
outputList <-
    lapply(1:3, FUN = function(ii) {
        label <- dfNames[ii]
        df <- dfList[[ii]]
        dt <- data.table(df, key=c("site", "run", "id"))
        groups <- unique(dt[,key(dt), with=FALSE])
        groups[, stream := seq_len(nrow(groups))]
        dt <- dt[groups]
        # Note: The following line only keeps the first 3 (rather than 20) rows
        dt <- dt[, head(cbind(.SD, i=seq_len(.N)), 3), by=stream]
        dt <- cbind(label, dt[,c("stream", "dir", "i", "payload")])
        df <- as.data.frame(dt)
        return(df)
    })
output <- do.call(rbind, outputList)
})
##    user  system elapsed 
##    1.25    0.18    1.44 

## Have a look at the output
rbind(head(output,4), tail(output,4))
```

---

**EDIT**: On 5/8/2012, I cut run-time of the above by ~25% by substituting this line:

```
dt <- dt[, head(cbind(.SD, i=seq_len(.N)), 3), by=stream]
```

for these two:

```
dt <- cbind(dt, i = dt[, list(i=seq_len(.N)), by=stream][[2]])
dt <- dt[i<=3,]  # Note: This only keeps the 1st 3 (rather than 20) rows
```

Comment: Great. Btw, I'm working on := by group which'll simplify the cbind(dt,i=dt[...]) line. I guess you found that to be much faster than head(.SD,3).

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Actually, I just assumed anything involving `.SD` would be slower, but of course that can't actually be true. I just now tried `head(.SD,3)`, and it's ~ 25% faster, so I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Also, I'm *thrilled* to hear that you're working on making `group` and `:=` work together. Even if it doesn't speed up anything at all, it'll make the syntax of many calls much simpler and more expressive, and will also lower the hump that beginning users need to get over. Thanks!

Comment: Great. The `cbind` of `.SD` will be copying all of the group's data each time though. How about just coping the head and adding `i` to that (since OP needs `i`):  head(.SD,3)[,i:=seq_len(.N)]. That needs dev v1.8.1 for `j` to see `.N`. In v1.8.0 you have to pick a column: `head(.SD,3)[,i:=seq_len(length(stream))]`.

Comment: And on `:=` by group, yes I'm looking forward to it too. In implementing it have tackled a few internal inefficiencies, so it should be faster for joins in general as well, particularly when there's both `i` and `by` supplied in the same query.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Using `head(.SD,3)[,i:=seq_len(.N)]` is a clever idea, but when using either it or the other suggestion, I still get the `Combining := in j with by is not yet implemented` message. Surprising, since the `:=` is in a separate (but nested) call to `[,]`. Does it work for you?

Comment: Oops, no doesn't work yet. Have added FR to test that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. That nested `:=` is tested in v1.8.3 on R-Forge now; i.e., `DT[,head(.SD,3)[,i:=seq_len(.N)],by=grp]`. Perhaps not as needed now that `:=` by group is done, but the use case might be when using `.SDcols` followed by a `:=` by the same grouping. That could be done in one grouping now.